# Why MemberAccessException not throwing?

Tags: c#, exception, reflection

simple code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();

        //Expect MemberAccessException here
        //(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.method.aspx)
        Console.WriteLine("Delegate.Method: " + a.ACallback.Method); 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public delegate void TestCallback();

class A
{
    public TestCallback ACallback;

    public A()
    {
        ACallback = new TestCallback(this.Some);
    }

    private void Some()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Call Some");
    }
}
```

And didn't catch any exception, why?

Comment: Why do you expect a `MemberAccessException`?

Comment: Because caller does not have access to the method represented by the delegate, the method is private.

Comment: Possibly some verifications are disabled in full trust scenarios.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: what's mean - full trust scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

from MSDN: [Delegate.Method Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.method.aspx)

> MemberAccessException: The caller does not have access to the method
>   represented by the delegate (for example, if the method is private).

but your `A.ACallback` is `public`.

Comment: So, when I can get exception MemberAccessException, while I try to access to property "Method" of some delegate?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your code is perfectly valid ... if you are expecting an exception to be thrown because you are trying to access a private member of the delegate your logic is incorrect. You are calling the private method via a public member of the class so this works just fine.

Making TestCallback private would result in a compile time error I'm not sure how you expect to generate a MemberAccessException?

Comment: I expect exception (MemberAccessException) when I try to access to Method property of delegate. Because caller does not have access to the method represented by the delegate, the method is private.

Comment: @Nick: your assumption is wrong, passing a reference to a private field, property or method has always allowed external code to use what is referenced by that "pointer", this is valid from the times of C and C++, I asked same question in the university about 12 years ago and was surprised as well, but this is the way things work :)

Comment: @Davide C and C++ are not relevant here.

Comment: Can you show me simple example code, which raise exception MemberAccessException in Delegate.Method Property, please?

Comment: I think you are getting confused by the fact that you are accessing a private member ... but you aren't accessing it directly. You are passing a Public field and then accessing the private member through it. Because it is a member of that class it can and does access the private member. So you can't do `a.Some();` .. that would be a compile error. But you are using the public field TestCallBack .. and under the covers it uses Some() ... and this is just fine :)

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I know, but same thing with getting access via pointer or reference to something private which allows you to use it from outside afterwards, just an example...

Comment: @iDevForFun: I didn't confused in delegate calling, I just remove that code. I confused in a.ACallback.Method . I expect exception in this point

Comment: I don't think you'll get this code to throw that exception ...

From MSDN ... 

MemberAccessException is thrown by the following methods:

Invoke of the System.Reflection classes, GetValue of the FieldInfo class, and **DynamicInvoke of the Delegate class**.

Link ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.memberaccessexception.aspx

I think to get the error you are after you would need to be using reflection with Activator.CreateInstance().